# How to fix Misra 2012 violation , " Assignment operation in expression "

Tags: c, macros, bit-manipulation, misra

I am trying to clear a bit in a 32bit variable using macro. eg.

```
#define CLEAR_BIT( VAR, BIT )       ( VAR &= ~( BIT ) )
```

in function, I have called macro as

```
CLEAR_BIT(variable, 0x01 );
```

In this case, I am getting MISRA C - 2012 violation as " Assignment operation in the expression"  " MISRA-C:2012 R.13.1, R.13.2, R.13.4 "

If someone can let me know, What I am doing wrong as per MISRA C rules?

Comment: By having paranthesis around the macto expansion, it has become an expression. Change to: `VAR &= ~( BIT )`

Comment: Same violation exists.

Comment: It's an expression with or without the parentheses.  *Every* assignment is an expression.  But I agree that it's probably the presence of the parentheses that cause the validator to flag it.

Comment: Is this really what the original code looks like? If not, post it. If so, please name the static analyser used, so that we may shame them to the internet public.

Comment: OT: There also should be parenthesis around `VAR`.

Comment: I have tried with and without parenthesis, even the typecasting. But all in vain

Comment: What does the code before and after the macro call look like? Instead of parentheses you can use `do { … } while (0)` for macro statements.

Comment: The recommendation to take away the parentheses around the macro expansion just to please an analysis tool (which is likely buggy anyway) is bad advise.  Better to turn the macro into a statement as proposed by @starblue.  But, as long as it remains an expression, it would be bad practice to remove the parentheses.  It always makes me nervous to find people meddling with their code in a trial-and-error way to make one or the other warning go away...

Answer (score 3):

If you truly call the macro as `CLEAR_BIT(variable, 0x01 );` and not for example `if(CLEAR_BIT(variable, 0x01)) ...` then the warning is wrong and the tool is broken.

The rule 13.4 is what applies here, stating that you aren't allowed to mix assignment with other expressions (the result of an assignment operation should not be used). From what we can tell from the code posted, you aren't doing that.

Also, there's no unintended side effects of this code as those other rules 13.1 to 13.2 are about. Compound assignment only evaluates the left operand once, so it shouldn't matter if it is `volatile` etc.

You have other problems with this code, such as using a signed integer constant `0x01`, and depending on the type of the variable, potentially various violations of implicit promotion rules, use of function-like macros. But those problems should give entirely different warnings.

Comment: I have mentioned the flow of my code below:

#define BIT_1                                   0x01u

#define CLEAR_BIT( VAR, BIT )       VAR &= ~(BIT)
volatile uint32 var2 = 0u
uint32 VAR_1 = 0x00000000U;
VAR_1  = var2 ;
CLEAR_BIT( VAR_1, BIT_1 );

This is how the code is working.

Comment: @PriyadarshiniSingh Ok, so it seems likely to be a bug in the static analyser. It's not uncommon, these tools are often very broken.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Will check with the tool suite.

Answer (score 0):

If the above-mentioned macro is redefined as

```
# define CLEAR_BIT( VAR, BIT )       ( VAR) &= (~( BIT ) )
```

Then the code will be compliance with Misra rules.

The error of "Assignment operation in the expression" " MISRA-C:2012 R.13.1, R.13.2, R.13.4 " will occur when we write MACRO expansion within brackets (). I.e.,

`#define CLEAR_BIT( VAR, BIT )       ( VAR &= ~( BIT ) )`